# Is there a .Net Reporting tool that uses Office templates?

Tags: .net, excel, ms-word, reporting, ms-office

On the application I am currently working on, we need a way for users to generate reports in Microsoft Word or Excel format (export and print).

One of the requirement is that the users would create the report template using a Word or Excel template document.

I've tried to google a reporting tool that uses word and excel templates for report templates and the only one I found (Windwards) is way too expensive and wouldn't fit our needs. We cannot have a server to generate the reports, so the report would need to be generated directly by the application (Windows Forms).

Comment: Gimly - I'm the founder/CTO at Windward. We also have a less expensive product where you can incorporate the reporting into your application. No server required. (And we just released a SAAS version too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are to limited in the solution that you search. Why must the template editor based on Word and/or Excel. This both programs are document editors. A template editor based on this programs are very limited and can not produced a good template editor. I see no difference if you call Word or any third party program.

Because reports based in the most cases on data from database that it make sense to install it on the server where the data are.

I think you ask the wrong questions. The more interest question are:

- support for my data (DBMS, XML, etc.)
- reporting features like sorting, grouping, joining, charts, crosstabs, form print, etc.
- needed user experience, should the designer used from the application developer, the network administrator or from the end user. In last case a Ad Hoc reporting is better as a completely reporting designer.

Comment: I understand your point of view, and you are certainly correct. The trouble is that the application already contains some kind of report and the users are already used to creating reports on Excel.
Considering the way the application is distributed to the customers it would be really difficult to have a specialised server for reporting as well.
Maybe a reporting tool is over the top for our needs, all we need for now is to print labels easily from some data that we have in our database (adresses for example)

Answer (score 1):

There is kind of an alternative to Windwards reports - [Templater](http://templater.info).
It's also based on **tags**, but more lightweight.